# Manage session in loopback

Tags: loopbackjs

I am creating a application using loopback.i am facing a problem to manage session.When apps login, session is created. when i reload the page session is not present on client side but it is on server side. Please tell me how to manage session on client side. And how to send response from server to client. Sorry for english but I am trouble.
Please tell me about it.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you post the code you are currently using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can inject `$sessionStorage` in angular and use it to preserve the session information that you get back from loopback.

But I believe that loopback already has the ability to [store the access token](http://docs.strongloop.com/display/public/LB/AngularJS+JavaScript+SDK#AngularJSJavaScriptSDK-Persistingtheaccesstoken) in the browser's localStorage, so it is preserved across page reloads and browser (hybrid mobile app) restarts. So I'm not sure why it gets lost for you ... or maybe that's not what you mean by "page session"? Feel free to clarify.

You can see an example of logging in and then saving the user info to browser here: https://github.com/ShoppinPal/warehouse/blob/f03abc632ac01682e938e58db868290fb6e33083/client/app/scripts/controllers/login.js#L35-L42

If you ever find yourself in a similar situation again, try searching for code on `github.com` as there is some chance that you might find what you're looking for in an open-source project.

For example, you can get decent hints if you [searched](https://github.com/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=user+model+sessionStorage+path%3A%2Fclient%2Fapp) for `user model sessionStorage path:/client/app` where `user model sessionStorage` are keywords to look for and `path:/client/app` represents (more or less) the standardized directory structure for loopback (`path:/client/js` is another common path to try) ... it is generally worth limiting your search with it ... this helps narrow down thousands of search results into double digits. I do admit however that it doesn't always work because if you didn't know to look for the `sessionStorage` keyword then the search would have been quite fruitless ;)